# Failure to converge for ordinal logistic regression or Model nearly unidentifiable with large eigenvalue

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression, ordinal

Depending on which optimizer I use for this ordinal logistic regression I receive one of two errors.

This one:

```
logit <- clm(y ~ ., data = train, link = 'logit', method = 'optim')
Warning message:
(-1) Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 327.509 (tol = 1e-06)
```

Or this one:

```
logit <- clm(y ~ ., data = train, link = 'logit', method = 'Newton')
Warning message:
(2) Model is nearly unidentifiable: very large eigenvalue
 - Rescale variables? 
In addition: Absolute and relative convergence criteria were met
```

My response variable has 10 ordered categories, there are 9 independent variables where 8 are percents and the last one's values range from 9 - 1000.

There are no columns with all 0's, NA's are removed, and I have rescaled all of the independent variables to no avail.

I would be grateful for any assistance on this problem. Thank you.